# Como puedo agrupar y sumar este tipo de array?

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una duda llevo horas tratando de resolverlo pero no he encontrado alguna solución.

Tengo un arreglo que viene de una bd el cual es dinámico entre meses y cantidades, el cual es para usarlo para mostrar unas gráficas, lo que necesito es agrupar los meses y sumar sus respectivos valores.
Alguna solucion?
Gracias de antemano.

```
 {"data":[["Mes","CLP"],["Nov",290709],["Dic",9283],["Ene",234066],["Ene",114465]]}
```

la idea es que quede con los meses agrupados y las cantidades sumadas, en este caso asi:

```
{"data":[["Mes","CLP"],["Nov",290709],["Dic",9283],["Ene",348531]]}
```

La query es la siguiente

```
public function graficoMesesTecnico($tecnico,$desde,$hasta,$tipo){
        $this->db->select("SHA1(i.id) as 'hash_id',
            i.id as id,
            it.tipo as especialidad,
            it.id as id_especialidad,
            it.precio_baremo_1 as precio_baremo_1,
            it.precio_baremo_2 as precio_baremo_2,
            it.porcentaje_maestro as porcentaje_maestro,
            it.porcentaje_ayudante1 as porcentaje_ayudante1,
            it.porcentaje_ayudante2 as porcentaje_ayudante2,

            i.maestro as rut_maestro,
            i.maestro2 as rut_maestro2,
            i.ayudante1 as rut_ayudante1,
            i.ayudante2 as rut_ayudante2,
            CONCAT(u1.primer_nombre,' ',u1.apellido_paterno) as 'maestro',
            CONCAT(u2.primer_nombre,' ',u2.apellido_paterno) as 'ayudante1',
            CONCAT(u3.primer_nombre,' ',u3.apellido_paterno) as 'ayudante2',
            CONCAT(u5.primer_nombre,' ',u5.apellido_paterno) as 'maestro2'
            ");

            $this->db->from('movistar_informes_de_avance as i');
            $this->db->join('usuario as u1', 'u1.rut = i.maestro', 'left');
            $this->db->join('usuario as u2', 'u2.rut = i.ayudante1', 'left');
            $this->db->join('usuario as u3', 'u3.rut = i.ayudante2', 'left');
            $this->db->join('usuario as u5', 'u5.rut = i.maestro2', 'left');
            $this->db->join('movistar_especialidades as it', 'it.id = i.id_tipo', 'left');
            $this->db->where('i.estado', 3);

            if($tipo=="1"){
                $this->db->where('(i.ayudante1="'.$tecnico.'" or i.ayudante2="'.$tecnico.'")');
            }else if($tipo=="3"){
                $this->db->where('i.maestro', $tecnico);
            }

            $this->db->where("i.fecha_ingreso BETWEEN '".$desde."' AND '".$hasta."'");              
            $this->db->order_by('i.fecha_ingreso', 'asc');
            $res=$this->db->get();
            //echo $this->db->last_query();

            $temp=array();
            $temp[] = array("Mes","CLP"); 
            $puntos_baremos=0;

        foreach($res->result_array() as $key){
            $this->db->select('(CAST(mmo.puntos_baremos AS DECIMAL(10,3))*sum(md.cantidad_mano_obra)) as "totalpb",
                MONTH(m.fecha_ingreso) as mes',false);

            $this->db->from('movistar_informes_de_avance_detalle as md');
            $this->db->join('movistar_informes_de_avance as m', 'm.id = md.id_informe', 'left');
            $this->db->join('movistar_mano_de_obra as mmo', 'mmo.id = md.id_mano_obra', 'left');
            $this->db->join('movistar_unidad_de_obra as muo', 'muo.id = md.id_unidad_obra', 'left');
            $this->db->where('id_informe', $key["id"]);

            $this->db->group_by('md.id_mano_obra');
            /*$this->db->group_by('MONTH(m.fecha_ingreso)');
            $this->db->group_by('YEAR(m.fecha_ingreso)');*/

            $res2=$this->db->get();
            foreach($res2->result_array() as $key2){
                $puntos_baremos=$puntos_baremos+(floatval($key2["totalpb"]));
            }


            if($tipo==1){//AYUDANTE

                $nombre=$key["ayudante1"];
                $str="0.".$key["porcentaje_ayudante1"];
                $baremos_individual=$puntos_baremos*(float)$str;
                $clp_individual=$baremos_individual*$key["precio_baremo_1"];

            }elseif($tipo==3) {//MAESTRO

                $nombre=$key["maestro"];
                $str="0.".$key["porcentaje_maestro"];
                $baremos_individual=$puntos_baremos*(float)$str;
                $clp_individual=$baremos_individual*$key["precio_baremo_1"];
            }

            $temp[] = array($this->mes_corto($key2["mes"]),(float)round($clp_individual)); 
            $puntos_baremos=0;
        }

        $filas = $temp;
        return $filas;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Lo quieres hacer en PHP o JavaScript? Son lenguajes diferentes.

Comment: hola, cualquiera de los 2.

Comment: Apoyanos agregando el código fuente que estas empleando y si es posible el query que estas ejecutando, así tendrás ayuda más acertada.

Comment: Vale, , edite arriba y la coloque. Es horrible la query, no pude hacerla con sola una, tube q crear una y recorrerla para agregar otra query y de ahi armarme un array.

Comment: Por favor, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. La mayor parte del código compartido no parece necesario para solucionar el problema.

Comment: Claro que puedo compartirlo no hay problema.

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es esto: `{"data":[["Mes","CLP"],["Nov",290709],["Dic",9283],["Ene",348531]]}` entonces pídele a tu consulta (PHP), que te mande los datos así, de lo contrario, estarás transportando datos para luego tirar parte de ellos. Eso te saldrá caro. Tú no le pagas el viaje a Australia a 200 personas para luego trabajar con 10 (por poner un ejemplo). ¿Qué hacen las 190 mientras? ¿Cuánto gastarás para alojarlas y alimentarlas? Al final terminarás quebrado. Selecciona a tus 10 personas antes de llevártelas para Australia. Pues lo mismo, !selecciona justamente los datos que necesitas!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto te sirva:

```js
var data = {"data":[["Mes","CLP"],["Nov",290709],["Dic",9283],["Ene",234066],["Ene",114465]]};

var months = {};

data.data.forEach(function( dat ) {

  var m = dat[0], //mes
     n = parseInt( dat[1] ); //valor
      
  /* Esto es simplemente para tomar solo los valores numéricos */
  if ( !n ) return;
 
  if ( !months.hasOwnProperty( m ) ) {
   months[m] = n;
  } else {
   months[m] += n;
  }

});

console.log( months );
```

Ten en cuenta que de este modo consigues un objeto con los meses en orden siempre y cuando se reciban en orden de la base de datos, si no habría que hacer algunos ajustes más.

Con el objeto resultante ya puedes trabajar cómodamente con los valores, esto se puede hacer de muchas maneras, pero de esta manera que te he mostrado puede serte bastante útil.
Esto es un ejemplo en JavaScript pero no sería muy diferente en PHP, es más que nada para que te hagas una idea.

Comment: vale , voy a intentar transformar la data resultante al array inicial y estaria solucionado, gracias!

Comment: Filtros? Y como lo harías en PHP , digo para que no se tenga q convertir?

Comment: @RicardoAntonioHernández a filtros me refería a filtrar el array en caso de que no estuvieran en orden, o desechar valores innecesarios, sinceramente programé durante un tiempo en PHP pero en seguida me pasé a Node JS, por lo tanto no sabría muy bien explicartelo en PHP. El ejemplo que te puse es simplemente para tener los valores listo para mostrarlos en tu web.